# Prove that $P(x)$ has a real zero

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, real-numbers

Suppose that $P(x)$ is a polynomial with real coefficients such that for some positive real numbers $c$,$d$ and for all natural numbers $n$, we have $$c {\left| n \right|}^3 \leq \left| P(n) \right| \leq d {\left| n \right|}^3$$
Prove that $P(x)$ has a real zero.

I knew that a polynomial of odd degree has a real zero. But, I was unable to show it. Well, thanks to the answers and comments, now I can.

Comment: Hint : look at the degree of $P(x)$.

Comment: I just have no idea how to start. I don't know much about polynomials. @NoahSchwebber

Comment: Dear downvoter, if you really think it's a dumb question, then please help me giving the solution.

Comment: @SayantanSantra Try to work out the hint given above (by Clément Guérin). Followup hint: if a real polynomial has odd degree, what can you say about its limits at $\pm\infty$?

Comment: Well, the signs of the limits are different. And they are $\pm \infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint:* Consider these limits and conclude something about the degree of $P$:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{P(n)}{n^3}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^3}{P(n)}
$$
Recall that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{P(n)}{Q(n)} =
\cases{
\pm \infty, & if $\deg P > \deg Q$\\
a\ne 0, & if $\deg P = \deg Q$\\
0, & if $\deg P < \deg Q$\\
}
$$

Solution:

> We conclude that $\deg P =3$. Therefore, it must have a real zero: every polynomial of odd degree has at least one real zero (actually, an odd number of real zeros).

Comment: Well, $c \leq \frac{P(n)}{n^3} \leq d \; \forall n$. So, the limit must be finite and not zero. So, the polynomial has a degree $3$. Am I right?

Comment: @SayantanSantra, yes.

Comment: And, if I'm not mistaken, every polynomial with an odd degree has a real root. Right?

Comment: @SayantanSantra, yes.

Comment: It's really a nice answer